# SharePoint 2013 - How to set a default custom page layout to a master template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

within SharePoint 2013 and from the browser, How do I set the default custom page layout to a master template?

Comment: What you mean by `Master Template`?

Comment: Sorry - I mean "Site Master Page"

Comment: I want my custom calendar page located under /_Layouts/15/ to have a custom page layout...how do we set a default layout for the Site Master Page that is displaying my Calendar in that directory?

Comment: I saw you initial question. The aspx page you are talking is not in `layout` folder. Please read my answer and open the page in the SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual Page you are talking about is

```
 https://my-custom-site/Lists/Calendar/calendar.aspx
```

Its using `_layouts/15/start.aspx` is because of some new features (caching) implemented in SP2013.

The master page used by the page `calendar.aspx` can be reviewed by opening the Site Settings -> Look and Feel (Master Page)

If you want to change the master of only this page, then you can edit the page in SharePoint Designer and change the `Page` directive.

Comment: I need a little more specific direction - I need to set the default custom page layout for "any" master template I want.  How do I do that...? For example one master template has a curtain custom page layout as default, while another master template has another custom page layout as default.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by Master Template. Is it Master Page you are talking about?

Comment: Yes.  I am able to change the Master Page.  I just want to change the custom page layout for the page too that already exist, but don't know how to do that for this calendar page.

Comment: ok, I think I found the issue here...I cannot apply a custom page layout to a web part page (which is what this is on). I will need to create a duplicate Master Page and style that new Master Page directly.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear enough. I believe the Calendar page is an out of the box page?

Comment: Yes it is, and in order for me to apply a custom look and feel to it (a layout I personally create), I have to make sure that it's master template is linking to my CSS /JS files.

Comment: You just need to create a custom master page and then set it to the site. If you are only targeting that single page, then you can edit that page using designer and add the css/js only to that page.

Comment: Thank you so much for confirming that Amal!  We are looking good now!!!